# My simple code for taking picture and get thumbnail not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i've just started coding, by learning java and now i'm into android dev

i wanted to create a simple app where you can take a photo with phone camera and get the thumbnail

my java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnTakePic;
ImageView imageView;
String pathToFile;
//Bouton et ImageView
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    btnTakePic = findViewById(R.id.btn_takePic);
    btnTakePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dispatchPictureTakerAction();
        }
    });
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
}
//Aperçu de l'image
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == 1){
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
//Prise de photo Phonecam
private void  dispatchPictureTakerAction() {
    Intent takePic = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePic.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        photoFile = createPhotoFile();

        if (photoFile != null) {
            pathToFile = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "toto", photoFile);
            takePic.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePic, 1);


        }
    }
}
//Creation/Sauvegarde de l'image
private File createPhotoFile() {
    String name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmsss ").format(new Date());
    File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image =  null;
    try {
        image = File.createTempFile(name,".jpg", storageDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("mylog","Excep : " + e.toString());
    }
    return image;
}}
```

the code is running without error but the takephoto button isn't working :/

Comment: if you're "just starting", maybe you should start with learning the basics.

Answer (score 0):

read this [how to take photo](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics). Your `dispatchPictureTakerAction()` is completely wrong, you have to start camera intent first to take photo.

and then handle it this way:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val imageBitmap = data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
    }
```